# jupyter-notebookが起動できません。

Tags: jupyter-notebook

anacondaをインストールする時、ユーザー名を漢字名を使用しているのでC：直下にanacondaをインストールしました。
jupyter-notebookがanacondaからも、スタート画面からも立ち上げ出来ません。
スタート画面からならspyderは立ち上げ可能です。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

添付されているスクリーンショットは、Anaconda Prompt で `jupyter-notebook` コマンドを実行したところでしょうか。そうでしたら、これで起動できています。

ログの最後に出力されている URL をコピーしてブラウザからアクセスしてください。

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=なんとかかんとか
```

ログには次のように書かれていますが、

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
```

これは「このURLにブラウザでアクセスすると notebook を開けるよ」という意味です。

Comment: この後に何かコマンドプロンプトを入力するのでしょうか？

Comment: しません。ブラウザでは開けませんでしたか？