# Jupyter Notebookの起動ができません。

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Windows10にAnacondaをインストールしましたが、Jupyter Notebookが下記の状態から進まず、起動できません。

誰か、何が原因なのか教えてください。尚、東京太郎は仮名です。

```
[I 12:52:48.883 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 12:52:48.884 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 12:52:48.887 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\東京太郎
[I 12:52:48.887 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 12:52:48.887 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=718f14dc42c98861aee382764b5e3867fe3caa1d43e56340
[I 12:52:48.887 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=718f14dc42c98861aee382764b5e3867fe3caa1d43e56340
[I 12:52:48.887 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:52:48.980 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/%E5%B0%8D%E9%A6%AC%E3%80%80%E6%96%89/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-11908-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=718f14dc42c98861aee382764b5e3867fe3caa1d43e56340
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=718f14dc42c98861aee382764b5e3867fe3caa1d43e56340
e
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2299c0fc9e6a7994a87c731c0c08f155f98ca42f5dedd19e
```

Comment: 重複候補(回答あり): [Jupyter-notebookが起動できません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60153/3060)

Answer (score 1):

`Jupyter Notebook` で ユーザ名の漢字対応が ちゃんとできていないことが原因だと思います。

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/%E5%B0%8D%E9%A6%AC%E3%80%80%E6%96%89
```

の `%E5...` の部分に 東京太郎さんのユーザ名が URL エンコードされてはいっています。

コマンドプロンプトを開いて
`start %APPDATA%\jupyter\runtime`
を入力して 開いたフォルダから 
`nbserver-11908-open.html`
ファイルを開いてみてください。